# Generate CakePHP password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cakephp, md5

I'm trying to write the equivalent of

```
$password = Security::hash('text pw', null, true)
```

In CakePHP, that creates a security hash that will validate for "text pw" when a user logs in. I tried so far, in Rails:

```
password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("text pw")
```

But that doesn't authenticate when I try to log into the CakePHP app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Were you using sha1 or md5?

Comment: Yep, added an answer. It was sha1 but I think this can vary by individual Cake install. SHA1 is probably typical though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeff Ancel was really close. This is how Cake does it and what I ended up using:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
hashed_pw = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(cake_security_salt + text_password)
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I was working on this last night and got it to work as well. I had a similar solution but I needed to add a function to override valid_password? in my users controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873398/rails-devise-legacy-users-from-cakephp

Answer (score 2):

I like the suggestion above, but  it seems you want to do this in Rails.  This is a ruby class, so you don't really need any plugins, etc.

```
  require 'digest/sha1'
  pass_hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{self.password}#{salt}")
```

I'm not 100% sure how cake does it, but referring to cakePhp docs or code should lend you insight there.

How are you trying to log in to a cakePhp app through rails?  My assumption is you're trying to move a cakePhp database to Rails?  Or perhaps port CakePhp Authentication to rails?

Comment: Thanks I think the problem might be that I was a) using the wrong encryption type and b) not sure how to integrate the salt (which is a string defined in our Cake app). I'm using it to create a user via a Rails API that will be able to login to the main CakePHP app. I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The security class uses the SHA1 scheme by default, and cakephp also uses a salt which you set in your config.php to generate an even more unique hash. You could replicate it in ruby just find a library that does SHA1 and pass it the same salt as your cakephp app. Or alternatively, you could switch cakephp to use MD5 for it's password hashing with:

```
Security::setHash('md5'); // or sha1 or sha256.
```

and also see here from the cakebook - http://book.cakephp.org/view/1254/Change-Hash-Function