# Migrating passwords to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm migration users database from PHP to Rails. I have already instaled Devise Gem and it is working well now. Also, I have found a hint how to migrate existing users' passwords to Rails
I have added old passwords to same `encrypted_password` field as Devise holds, so when devise fails to auth, checking for old password:

```
# user.rb      
def valid_password?(password)
  return false if encrypted_password.blank?
  require 'digest/sha1'
  password_salt = 'my_php_framework_salt'
  Devise.secure_compare(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password_salt+password), self.encrypted_password)
end
```

It allows to login with old passwords, but doesn't work with original Devise passwords for new users. I think this `valid_password?` method should `return true` for devise passwords.  How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you manually filled in `'my_php_framework_salt'` into the db rows for old users then just used:

`self.password_salt` instead of `password_salt` it would work.

As I remember ruby returns the result of the last line in a function. `Devise.secure_compare` should return a bool, which means `valid_password?` would return a boolean as well.

In short:

```
require 'digest/sha1'  

# ...

def valid_password?(password)
  return false if encrypted_password.blank?
  Devise.secure_compare(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password_salt+password), self.encrypted_password)
end
```